# Run arbitrary code in a Rails plugin on reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

I have built a rails plugin and it has a requirement of building some files to work correctly.   A user can manually kick this off as a rake task, but for convenience in development, I would like to add the option of rerunning this build whenever they refresh their browsers.

Just to be clear, I do not want to reLOAD the plugin every refresh, nor do I want to reload any other ruby file.  I would like to run some arbitrary ruby code every time Rails decides to reload it's libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this solution which is a bit more to the point.

```
ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
  Rails.logger.warn "Look at me I'm updating!"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**First solution:**

You have to add:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

In your Application class in config/application.rb

Please refer this link https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5218-rails-3-rc-does-not-autoload-from-lib

**Another One:**

It is more useful try it,

New file: `config/initializers/reload_lib.rb`

```
if Rails.env == "development"
  lib_reloader = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker.new(Dir["lib/**/*"]) do
    Rails.application.reload_routes! # or do something better here
  end

  ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
    lib_reloader.execute_if_updated
  end
end
```

It's disgusting but it's a hack. There might be a better way to trigger a full reload, but this works for me. My specific use case was a Rack app mounted to a Rails route so I needed it to reload as I worked on it in development.

Basically what it does is it checks if any files in `/lib` have changed (modified timestamp) since last loaded and then triggers a reload if they change.

I might also mention I have this in my `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Which just by default makes sure everything in my lib directory gets loaded.

Comment: Right.  The autoload is reloading the file, I don't have to put just  classes in there,  I can just put in immediately executed code.  That was pretty daft of me. I like the former because it will leave it to rails to figure out when to run the code without a conditional. Thanks!